# Java script changing color of element by ID

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, html

Hi there I'm trying to do validation for  a form I am working on, and I have written a function and used

```
document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.backgroundColor ='#FFFFFF';
```

I have tested my function to display an alert message box, for debugging purposes when 'trav_emer_med_insur' is checked the message box is displayed.  I have checked here and on countless other sites and they all say `getElementById.style.backgroundColor = 'color';` is the method to achieve what I am looking for.  I don't understand at this point why it is not working, everything appears correct.

Here is the starting, pertinent part of my function:

```
function validatePlanTypes(form)    {
    var error = "";

        if (form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked)   {
            document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
            if (!form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt1.checked || !form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt2.checked || !form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt3.checked || !form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt4.checked)   {
                form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt1.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt2.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt3.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                form.trav_emer_med_insur_opt4.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                error = "You must pick a plan-type for Travel Emergency Medical insurance, areas with a problem have been highlighted yellow for you.";
            }
```

I am not testing the full function yet, I am only trying to test the very first if statement at this time, as I said the if statement works and alert("bleh"); will display an alert if I check that box

Here is the HTML of the form where I am trying to change the background color of a span element surrounding the checkbox.

```
<p><span name="span_trav_emer_med_insur" id="span_trav_emer_med_insur" value="span_trav_emer_med_insur" style=""><input type="checkbox" name="trav_emer_med_insur" id="trav_emer_med_insur_if"  value="trav_emer_med_insur_if" class="form_elements" onClick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('trav_emer_med_options').style.display='block';}else{document.getElementById('trav_emer_med_options').style.display='none';}"/></span> <!-- Travel Emergency Medical If Box -->

                    <label class="form_elements" name="label_for_trav_emer_med_insur_if" id="label_for_trav_emer_med_insur_if">&nbsp;&nbsp;Travel Emergency Medical Insurance&nbsp;<em>(expands when checked)</em>.</label></p>
                    <p>

                    <div id="trav_emer_med_options" name="trav_emer_med_options" class="questions_hidden">
```

I have also tried

```
form.span_trav_emer_med_insur.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
```

Also to no avail, I'm really stumped here, the code looks identical to what I see all over the net.  Someone please tell me what I am missing.

Thanks,
-Sean

Edit - Just to verify:

```
if (form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked)   {
            alert("bleh");
```

instead of

```
if (form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked)   {
            document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
```

Does work, so the if statement or function is not a problem.

Complete file here - with getelementbyID not working - http://hotfile.com/dl/135598683/93484d4/general2.html

Complete file here with alert('bleh') WORKING - 
http://hotfile.com/dl/135598746/dc9e14b/general23.html

Working PHP code showing exactly what I'm trying to do (minus the page reload part):

```
    // Check if Emergency Medical is selected.
if (isset($_POST['trav_emer_med_insur']))   { 

    // If Emergency Medical is selected, then check to see if an option has been selected
    if (isset($_POST['trav_emer_med_insur_opt1']) or isset($_POST['trav_emer_med_insur_opt2']) or isset($_POST['trav_emer_med_insur_opt3']) or isset($_POST['trav_emer_med_insur_opt4']))   {

    $SQLString = $SQLString . "emer_med, emer_med_opt1, emer_med_opt2, emer_med_opt3, emer_med_opt4";

    }

    // If no option is selected display error message   
    else    {

        ++$ErrCount;
        $Errors[$ErrCount] = "You selected interest in Travel Emergency Medical Insurance  but did  not select a plan-type for it";

    }
}

// Check if All-Inclusive Insurance is selected.
elseif (isset($_POST['allinc_insur']))  {

    //If All-Inclusive Insurance is selected, then check to see if an option has been selected
    if (isset($_POST['allinc_insur_opt1']) or isset($_POST['allinc_insur_opt2']))   {

    }   

    //If no option is selected display error message
    else    {

        ++$ErrCount;
        $Errors[$ErrCount] = "You have selected interest in All-Inclusive Insurance but did not select a plan-type for it";

    }
}

// Check if Cancellation Insurance is selected.
elseif (isset($_POST['cancel_insur']))  {



}

// Check if Visitor Insurance is selected.
elseif (isset($_POST['visitor_insur'])) {

    //If Visitor Insurance is selected, then check to see if country is selected.
    if (isset($_POST['country_select']))    {

    }   

    // If no country selected display error message
    else    {

        ++$ErrCount;
        $Errors[$ErrCount]  = "You have selected interest in Visitor Insurance but have not selected a country";

    }       
}

//If no insurane types selected display error.
else    {

    ++$ErrCount;
    $Errors[$ErrCount] = "You haven not selected interest in any insurance plan types";

}
while ($Count != $Target)   {
    if (checked($QuestionNames[0]) != 1);
    ++$Count;
}
```

Comment: Which browser(s) is it not working in? Also, what is the `name` of your form tag?

Comment: Chrome it does not work in, just tested in FF, and IE, same thing. Firebug reports no syntax errors.

Comment: To GregL - My form is named mhc_form, and it is passed to my function with the onClick"" of the submit button.  As stated in my post, an alert box DOES spawn correctly from the if statement, so the function and if is working, but the style.backgroundcolor is non-responsive.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a test case? http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: You can view the complete file here: http://hotfile.com/dl/135598683/93484d4/general2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the span a colour from the start just to confirm you can see it?

As your code looks prefectly ok it could be the case that you just cannot see the span background colour.

For what it is worth I agree with the OP that using jquery for something trivial like this is a waste of bandwidth.

Based on your comments I created a test page to simulate yours.

This works:

`<span name="span_trav_emer_med_insur" id="span_trav_emer_med_insur" style='backgroundcolor:red'>
some words<input type="checkbox" name="trav_emer_med_insur" id="trav_emer_med_insur_if"  value="trav_emer_med_insur_if" class="form_elements" onClick="clck(this)"/>
</span> 
<label class="form_elements" name="label_for_trav_emer_med_insur_if" id="label_for_trav_emer_med_insur_if">  Travel Emergency Medical Insurance <em>(expands when checked)</em>.</label></p>
<div id="trav_emer_med_options" name="trav_emer_med_options" class="questions_hidden" style='display:none;'>
some hidden words
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clck(cbObj) {
if(cbObj.checked){
    document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.background = "green";
    document.getElementById('trav_emer_med_options').style.display='block';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.background = "red";
    document.getElementById('trav_emer_med_options').style.display='none';
}
}
</script>`

Comment: @SC1988 I have added a confirmed fix.

Comment: I have copied your page exactly into my editor and saved it as test.html - this does indeed work.  I copied the document.getElementById statements you used, exactly into my function. (which I have verified is to be working by use of alert box).  Nothing happens.......  The problem is that I need to do complete validation.  I appreciate your response and if it was simply single check boxes I had to validate this would be fine.  Unfortunately its a block of boxes, where one of 4 must be checked, and if 3 are checked, sub options for each box must be checked.  I could validate this in PHP

Comment: no problem at all.  However I do not want to have to have constant page reloads....

Comment: I have edited my OP to show confirmed working PHP code for what I want to do.  With the exception of changing the property color as well as doing an error message.  What I don't understand is that I have confirmed if(form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked) {} is working, with alert("bleh"); so why when I copy getElementById code which I have run in your file on my computer and confirmed to work, will not work, when the if statement preceding said code is working....

Comment: The only thing the span 'span_trav_emer_med_insur' contains is a checkbox, so setting the background colour will not make any difference as they do not have one. That is why I put some words in the span so the background colour is visible.

Comment: Yes but as can see in my full file here: http://hotfile.com/dl/135598683/93484d4/general2.html - Setting the style="background-color: red;" on the span, indeed put color around the checkbox.....

Comment: @SC1988. The id you are checking is wrong, it is not the checkbox id, you need to add '_if' to the end of it.

Comment: Yes but that if statement checks against mhc_form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked - the PHP name, not the CSS ID.  I've tested the IF  with alert("bleh"); - the alert box pops up.  Check http://hotfile.com/dl/135598746/dc9e14b/general23.html for example.  Sorry to seem unresponsive to your suggestions, but I am on the verge of smashing my screen in here, literally, I've checked every site on the first 4 pages of google and all confirm my code should work.

Comment: @SC1988 Move the alert to after the color change line. You will see the colour change then the page will reload & the colour will go back to red. My last comment

Comment: I went to the trouble of downloading and setting up your file as a page on my local server. What is happening, in Safari at least, is that the colour is being changed but then the form is submitted so the page is refreshed and thus the colour changes back to the default again. Putting the alert after the change colour line will stop the page refresh happening until the alert has been cleared.

Comment: Thanks.  That puts some more clarification on things.  However writing both statements in the if, whether the Alert or the color change first still has the color not changing.  Using the onclick on the box itself works, but that unfortunately won't work as I have multiple terms.  I'm going to use a work around by having the java function call the document submission, and make the submit button a normal button, so the page isn't reloaded.  I'll mark this as the answer as I suppose its the closest thing there is. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do this exact thing. I put extra brackets in and it worked.

As in:

```
(document.getElementById("advert")).style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of suggestions:

1. Use a JS framework - [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is the popular choice
2. Use Firebug for debugging
3. Set breakpoints in Firebug to figure out what (if anything) is breaking

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but using a framework is far too elaborate for my needs, I just need some simple if statements that change background color of an element (if applicable) or a span surrounding the element when it has not been filled in.  As I said I debugged by putting an alert('bleh'); in place of my color change statement.  When I checked the box and hit submit, the alert came up - meaning the if is working.  Code I copied off this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161154/javascript-function-to-change-button-colour at this link, does not work for me, but does for that guy??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying may not be the most productive approach.

You have two options here:

1. learn how to use your browser's consoele to find out why your style settings are not working by learning how things work from the ground up or,
2. go with jQuery which will make your life so much better.

Choice 1 is worth trying, you will learn a lot about what the DOM/CSS structures look like. To do this right mouse click and choose "inspect element" when your browser of choice repsonds look for the console and literally type "document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.backgroundColor" on the cmd line and see what you get. This is likely to be insightful.

If you want to get your job done quickly, get jQuery and try the following:

First to include jQuery on your page include a this line (there are other sources of jQuery as well):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in place of the code you were using:

```
  document.getElementById("span_trav_emer_med_insur").style.backgroundColor ='#FFFFFF';
```

use the following:

```
$("#span_trav_emer_med_insur").css("background", "#FFFFFF");
```

See how these two approaches differ? What you are attempting is to understand the low level structure of the browsers DOM model and what jQuery is doing for you is providing an abstraction you can understand, which is "please change the CSS style "background" to "yellow" for me.

I agree with the other's who have contributed, this is really the best course of action for you. It's well worth learning jQuery.

More on the jQuery CDN sites here [jQuery CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery)
[jQuery css call](http://api.jquery.com/css)

Comment: Added in jquery, both your code and 
$("span_trav_emer_med_insur").css("background-color", "#000000"); do not work either......

Comment: I appologise if my reply seemed condescending... I have been where you are and it's not fun so lets see if we can fix this for you. First, 
I noticed an error in the code I supplied you. You were doing getElementByID  so change the string in the code from "span_trav_emer_med_insur" to "#span_trav_emer_med_insur" - the '#' char means you are selecting an ID

Comment: Sorry perhaps I'm just frustrated and mis-read your post.  I will try that.

Comment: Still nothing.  I really don't understand.  I've even shrunk, for testing purposes the function to be simply this:
`code`
function validatePlanTypes(form) {
 var error = "";

  if (form.trav_emer_med_insur.checked) {
   alert("DO SOMETHING");
  }
  else {

  } 
 }`code`
Again, I can generate an alert box, but no style properties - of any kind, work.  I've even tried using style.display="none";, also used both jQuery and regular Jscript.  Still nothing.  I don't understand....

Comment: Let's try the jQuery on the command line (I suggest the right click "inspect element" as a means to get the console window up. This works really well in Chrome or Safari and the latest versions of Firefox). If you can get a command line operating try the following: $("#span_trav_emer_med_insur") this should return a javascript array [div... ] presuming your element is a div. It is very important that you have the string for your id exactly correct. If you get this far please show us what the return result was.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, if you want so set a background-color with javascript you access (and modify) the .style.backgroundColor property.

So I suppose the problem might be the html (and the styles), check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hqKwd/4/ I set the backgroundColor of a span that's empty, and nothing happends, but after 2 seconds I modify the innerHTML and you can see the color. The thing I'm trying to show is that being an span, it doesn't have display:block, so if you don't add that style or modify the content, you can't see anything.

Another thing might be that the property is being override by another piece of code, but apparently this is not the case

Hope it helps.

Comment: As you can see in the updated OP I have uploaded my HTML files.  Those HTML files both have the span set to RED by default, for testing purposes.  The style is working and isn't being overridden.  What would appear to be happening is working, valid code is simply choosing not do what it is supposed to do.... It makes no sense.